# Tira's mood changes: Is there random chance involved in whether the switch occurs

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I've been playing as Tira and I've noticed that changing her mood doesn't always work. For the most part it almost seems random. Is it based on any factors? I also noticed that after several `A+B` mood changes she seems to get a headache. Does this affect anything?

Comment: In SCIV, it was random. From my short time spent playing as Tira in SCV, it seems to work the same way that it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tira's stance changes *are* random, in the sense that there is not a dedicated combination to change her stances. They are not *completely* random; certain attacks and combos have a higher or lower chance of changing her stance, and she has a chance to change stance when taking damage.

From [8wayrun](http://8wayrun.com/threads/tira-general-discussion-q-a.9908/#post-390816) (combos changed by me for readability):

> It's still random when people are beating you up. Compared to SCIV, Tira stays in Gloomy Stance much longer in SCV. There are ways to to get out of Jolly Stance reliably.
>
> - 100% Mood switch - `JS 236236ABK`, `JS 66B~BE`, `236K~BE`, whiff `[A+B]`, `A+B`
> - High mood switch - `666B` (and `666B~BE`), `K+G`
> - Medium - `UD A`
> - Low - whiff `A+B`, `4K`, `66B` (I think)

It seems her `A+B` is often used; on a whiff (miss), it's got a pretty low chance, but on a hit, it's a very high chance.